# Create @Pip to apply filter during loop in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

the array dict as below

```
Data: Array<any> = [
      { name: 'A No',      dshow: true,    show: ''},
      { name: 'X No',      dshow: false,   show: false },
      { name: 'Y'   ,      dshow: false,   show: false }];
```

**UPDATED** HTML:

```
   <div  class="flex-child1 btn-group" *ngFor="let shw of Data; let i=index">
      <div *ngIf="(shwcol.dshow== false)">

        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" name= "{{shw.name}}" id= "{{shw.name}}" autocomplete="off" *ngIf="(shw.dshow== false)">
                
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="{{shw.name}}" *ngIf="(shw.dshow== false)">{{shw.name}}</label></div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.flex-child1 {
    flex: auto;
}
```

Above code generating two checkboxes and I guess one hidden chekbox    `X, Y`, the issue is empty space.

desire output `X Y`

**Updated** code helping not generate input for false values, but that generating button like   `X   Y`

Actual getting output after using updated code

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the CSS rules of the class names on the elements, preferably in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the update :) Sadly it doesn't clarify the question, but know that using `display: none` is different from `*ngIf`. `display: none` hides the element and leaves the space, while `*ngIf` removes the element completely if the condition is falsy.

Comment: Use https://angular.io/guide/pipes instead of *ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { IMyPipe } from "./app.component";

@Pipe({ name: "myPipe" })
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(item: IMyPipe): IMyPipe {
    if (!item.dshow) { // <--- your logic
      return item;
    }
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MyPipe } from "./my.pipe";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MyPipe],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

export interface IMyPipe {
  name: string;
  dshow: boolean;
  show: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: IMyPipe[] = [
    { name: "A No", dshow: true, show: false },
    { name: "X No", dshow: false, show: false },
    { name: "Y", dshow: false, show: false }
  ];
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div class="flex-child1 btn-group" *ngFor="let shw of data | myPipe">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="btn-check"
    name="{{shw.name}}"
    id="{{shw.name}}"
    autocomplete="off"
  />
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="{{shw.name}}">
    {{shw.name}} 
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @dmitry Grinko, really appreciate your time and afford. just one thing with your condition I am receiving error/waring on last `IMyPipe` in pipe.

Comment: I am receiving correct opposite ouput if I use `transform(shw: Show[]){
        return shw.filter(show => show.dshow);
    }`  I also tried `!=` not working can please help ?

Comment: the filter is an Array method. you cannot use it for an object.